# Javascript help w/exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, concatenation

So, I stuck with this code for hours.

```
function amountTocoins(amount, coins) {
    if (amount === 0) { 
        return []; 
    } else {
        if (amount >= coins[0]) { 
            left = (amount - coins[0]); 
            return [coins[0]].concat( amountTocoins(left, coins)); 
    } else {
            coins.shift();
            return amountToCoins(amount, coins);
       }
    }
 }
 document.write(amountTocoins(46, [25, 10, 5, 2, 1])); /25, 10, 10, 1
```

As I understand amount here is 46, and coins are 25, 10, 5, 2, 1, so followed by this, amount is greater than or equal to coins, which next piece of:

```
left = (amount - coins[0]);
```

is basically 25(zero-indexed), next;

```
return [coins[0]].concat( amountTocoins(left, coins));
```

concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays, but how is merged in this particular code? The output is: 25, 10, 10, 1, also I commented above in code.

I hope I described my problem well

Comment: Firstly the amount is 43 not 46 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you are dealing here with is a `recursion` - a phenomena when a function calls itself within it's body. You are calling your `amountTocoins` function within itself at two places (lines 6 and 9).

In your line:

```
return [coins[0]].concat( amountTocoins(left, coins));
```

the concatenation is halted until this new call to your `amountTocoins` function is executed and value returned. In your example your line is interpreted as:

```
return [25].concat(amountTocoins(21, [25, 10, 5, 2, 1]))
```

Until you execute `amountTocoins(21, [25, 10, 5, 1, 2])`, your `[25].concat(..)` function is not executed.

You'll go deeper and deeper, until you get to the bottom line condition that stops this nested function calls (recursion). In your case that condition is `amount === 0` which will return your first value that will be concatenated with, the empty array `[]`.

**Note:** you have a typo in your last `amountTocoins` function call (line 9).